# Calculating amount of available slots to fill

Tags: javascript, math, iteration

Imagine I have a 4x5 container that has 20 available slots inside. In this container, I have 13 squares and 7 circles:

[image]

But now the container shrinks to 3x3, with only 9 available slots.

I want to show the same ratio of squares to circles inside this smaller container, with the last of each being a stack of the items left over.

Right now, I'm taking the count of each type of item, divided by the total count of all items to get a percent value of how much that type makes up the total count, and then multiplying it by the container size:

```
const percentage = typeCount / totalCount;
const spaceUnrounded = percentage * availableSlots;
```

So this isn't the problem. The problem comes when I need to round this into an integer to get the correct amount of slots. Right now I'm finding the floor of the value:

```
const space = Math.floor(spaceUnrounded);
```

But this leads to the items leaving 1 space empty. I've also tried finding the ceiling of the value for the first type, and then the floor for the rest:

```
const space = index === 0 ? Math.ceil(spaceUnrounded) : Math.floor(spaceUnrounded);
```

But this can lead to the items adding 1 additional space, depending on the number of item types.

`Math.round` has the same issue.

What can I do here?

**EDIT:** My expected output would probably be 6 squares and 3 circles, as 13 is 65% of 20, and 65% of 9 is 5.85:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output, for example, from the image above?

Comment: The problem is that in your above example, you have an even number of squares. In your desired output, you have an odd number of squares. You need to work out how you want this additional square to be handled -- do you want it to be a square or a circle?

Comment: Updated with expected output. @ObsidianAge - Squares should never become circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick which number (circles or squares, doesn't matter) you want to be "authoritative" then subtract that number from the total number of slots to get the other number.

```
> slots = 20
> squares = 13
> circles = 7
> newslots = 9
> newsquares = Math.round(newslots/slots*squares)
6
> newcircles = newslots - newsquares
3
```

Comment: This works if there's only 2 types, but there's the potential for three or more. How would this work with `n` number of types?

Comment: Say you have N shapes:  `(n=1,2,3, N)`. Then for `n<N` use `newshapes[n] = Math.round(newslots/slots*shapes[n])` and for `shape[N]` use `newshape[N] = newslots - sum(newshapes[n<N])`.

Comment: Just got around to trying this out -- worked great, thanks!